# jQuery: how do I animate a div rotation?

Tags: jquery

I can rotate a div with css, and jquery .rotate, but i don't know how to animate it.

Comment: What kind of animation? Several are built into jQuery. There are even some with CSS 3.

Comment: just like the kind when you .animate, and give it different CSS properties... like I want it to rotate to the new position.

Comment: An example to your question is very helpful to answer. please provide an Example (if possible).

Comment: I just want a div. with anything in it. to rotate. but show the rotation as an animation, as if you were to do it by hand in real life.... =\

Comment: Check out this jQuery patch: http://www.zachstronaut.com/posts/2009/08/07/jquery-animate-css-rotate-scale.html Seems like it should do the trick!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Make use of `WebkitTransform / -moz-transform: rotate(Xdeg)`. This will not work in IE, but Matt's **[zachstronaut](http://www.zachstronaut.com/posts/2009/08/07/jquery-animate-css-rotate-scale.html)** solution doesn't work in IE either.

If you want to support IE too, you'll have to look into using a `canvas` like I believe **[Raphael does](http://raphaeljs.com/image-rotation.html)**.

Here is a simple jQuery snippet that rotates the elements in a jQuery object. Rotation can be started and stopped:

```js
$(function() {
    var $elie = $("img"), degree = 0, timer;
    rotate();
    function rotate() {
        
        $elie.css({ WebkitTransform: 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)'});  
        $elie.css({ '-moz-transform': 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)'});                      
        timer = setTimeout(function() {
            ++degree; rotate();
        },5);
    }
    
    $("input").toggle(function() {
        clearTimeout(timer);
    }, function() {
        rotate();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" value=" Toggle Spin " />
<br/><br/><br/><br/>
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/ABktns.jpg" />
```

Comment: @Steve Thanks for transferring the jsfiddle to this code snippet. That's awesome!

Comment: Awesome answer indeed, but it's apparently even easier in jQuery 1.8: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14016604/1450294

Answer (score 14):

If you're designing for an iOS device or just webkit, you can do it with no JS whatsoever:

CSS:

```
@-webkit-keyframes spin {  
from {  
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);  
}  
to {  
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);  
    } 
}

.wheel {
    width:40px;
    height:40px;
    background:url(wheel.png);
    -webkit-animation-name: spin; 
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite; 
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 3s; 
}
```

This would trigger the animation on load. If you wanted to trigger it on hover, it might look like this:

```
.wheel {
    width:40px;
    height:40px;
    background:url(wheel.png);
}

.wheel:hover {
    -webkit-animation-name: spin; 
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite; 
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 3s; 
}
```

Comment: @khaled_webdev that's why I said "If you're designing for an iOS device or just webkit"

Answer (score 10):

I've been using

```js
$.fn.rotate = function(degrees, step, current) {
    var self = $(this);
    current = current || 0;
    step = step || 5;
    current += step;
    self.css({
        '-webkit-transform' : 'rotate(' + current + 'deg)',
        '-moz-transform' : 'rotate(' + current + 'deg)',
        '-ms-transform' : 'rotate(' + current + 'deg)',
        'transform' : 'rotate(' + current + 'deg)'
    });
    if (current != degrees) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            self.rotate(degrees, step, current);
        }, 5);
    }
};

$(".r90").click(function() { $("span").rotate(90) });
$(".r0").click(function() { $("span").rotate(0, -5, 90) });
```

```css
span { display: inline-block }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>potato</span>

<button class="r90">90 degrees</button>
<button class="r0">0 degrees</button>
```

Comment: Nice! But in jQuery 1.8, there's apparently an easier way: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14016604/1450294

Answer (score 8):

If you want just a jQuery option, this will work:

```
$(el).stop().animate(
  {rotation: 360},
  {
    duration: 500,
    step: function(now, fx) {
      $(this).css({"transform": "rotate("+now+"deg)"});
    }
  }
);
```

This works with jQuery 1.8, which takes care of CSS prefixing automatically. jQuery doesn't animate rotation so I'm putting the `transform:rotate()` in the custom `step` function. It might only work starting from 0.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/forresto/ShUgD/

IE9 and Mobile Safari 4 support CSS transforms but not CSS transitions, so I came up with this simple shim, using Modernizr feature testing:

```
if (Modernizr.csstransitions) {
  $(el).css({
    "transition": "all 500ms ease-in-out"
  });
}

$(el).click(function(){
  var rotateTo = 360;
  if (Modernizr.csstransitions) {
    $(el).css({"transform": "rotate("+rotateTo+"deg)"});
  } else {
    $(el).stop().animate(
      {rotation: rotateTo},
      {
        duration: 500,
        step: function(now, fx) {
          $(this).css({"transform": "rotate("+now+"deg)"});
        }
      }
    );
  }
});
```

The above will use CSS transitions when available.

Answer (score 4):

As of now you still **can't** animate rotations **with jQuery**, but you **can with CSS3** animations, then simply **add and remove the class with jQuery to make the animation occur**.

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/jmex1p5g/)

---

**HTML**

```
<img src="http://puu.sh/csDxF/2246d616d8.png" width="30" height="30"/>
```

**CSS3**

```
img {
-webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
-o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
transform: rotate(-90deg);
transition-duration:0.4s;
}

.rotate {
-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
-o-transform: rotate(0deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
transform: rotate(0deg);
transition-duration:0.4s;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("img").mouseenter(function() {
        $(this).addClass("rotate");
    });
    $("img").mouseleave(function() {
        $(this).removeClass("rotate");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Based on Peter Ajtai answer, here is a small jquery plugin that may help others. I didn't test on Opera and IE9 but is should work on these browsers too.

```
$.fn.rotate = function(until, step, initial, elt) {
    var _until = (!until)?360:until;
    var _step = (!step)?1:step;
    var _initial = (!initial)?0:initial;
    var _elt = (!elt)?$(this):elt;

    var deg = _initial + _step;

    var browser_prefixes = ['-webkit', '-moz', '-o', '-ms'];
    for (var i=0, l=browser_prefixes.length; i<l; i++) {
      var pfx = browser_prefixes[i]; 
      _elt.css(pfx+'-transform', 'rotate('+deg+'deg)');
    }

    if (deg < _until) {
      setTimeout(function() {
          $(this).rotate(_until, _step, deg, _elt); //recursive call
      }, 5);
    }
};

$('.my-elt').rotate()
```

Comment: but what if rorate had 90deg => start form 0 ?  if run rotate() -> should show degree not rotate

Comment: To be able to rotate both directions:     ```var deg = (_initial < _step) ? _initial + _step : _initial - _step;```

Also, Jquery automatically does prefixing now.

Comment: The main issue with this solution is that it doesn't animate based on time like ```$.animate()```, so rotating 180º takes twice as long as 90º.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
function animateRotate (object,fromDeg,toDeg,duration){
    var dummy = $('<span style="margin-left:'+fromDeg+'px;">')
    $(dummy).animate({
        "margin-left":toDeg+"px"
    },{
        duration:duration,
        step: function(now,fx){
            $(object).css('transform','rotate(' + now + 'deg)');
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: This works way better than the other solutions for arbitrary start positions! Good job :).

Answer (score 0):

I needed to rotate an object but have a call back function.  Inspired by John Kern's answer I created this.

```
function animateRotate (object,fromDeg,toDeg,duration,callback){
        var dummy = $('<span style="margin-left:'+fromDeg+'px;">')
        $(dummy).animate({
            "margin-left":toDeg+"px"
        },
        {
            duration:duration,
            step: function(now,fx){
                $(object).css('transform','rotate(' + now + 'deg)');
                if(now == toDeg){
                    if(typeof callback == "function"){
                        callback();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    )};
```

Doing this you can simply call the rotate on the object like so... (in my case I'm doing it on a disclosure triangle icon that has already been rotated by default to 270 degress and I'm rotating it another 90 degrees to 360 degrees at 1000 milliseconds.  The final argument is the callback after the animation has finished.

```
animateRotate($(".disclosure_icon"),270,360,1000,function(){
                alert('finished rotate');
            });
```