# Animated rotate DIV on click

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery: how do I animate a div rotation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3789984/jquery-how-do-i-animate-a-div-rotation)

I have a div which I want to smoothly rotate around a center point by 30 degrees when you click it. I've searched a bunch but haven't found anything that I could get to work. Here's what I've tried so far - I can't for the life of me figure out what I'm doing wrong.

```
$("#box").click(function() {
    $(this).animate({
        rotate: '30deg'
    }, 1000);
});​
```

And here's an example: [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/svz2J/2/)

This seems stupidly simple and I'll probably get eaten alive for even asking, but I am seriously stuck on this. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Are you sure that element rotate animation can be done in such simple way? Consider using plugins or building up the animation logic by yourself.

Comment: To be honest I consider myself brain-dead when it comes to jQuery so I wouldn't have known if this was too simple or not to begin with haha, luckily this got answered perfectly.

Comment: this one also works for you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37452477/rotate-div-text-after-clicking-on-button-using-jquery-and-css

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [jQuery Rotate plugin](http://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/) - it's reasonably cross-browser.

```
$("#box").rotate({ 
    angle:0,
        bind: {
            click : function(){
                var curAngle = parseInt($(this).getRotateAngle());
                $(this).rotate({
                    angle: curAngle,
                    animateTo: curAngle + 30
                });
            }
        }
   });
```

​
**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/svz2J/6/

As requested in the comments below - a way to do this via a button.
Also, added a `duration` example.

```
$("button").click(function(){ 
    var curAngle = parseInt($("#box").getRotateAngle()) || 0;
    $("#box").rotate({
        angle: curAngle,
        animateTo: curAngle + 30,
        duration: 5000
    });
});
```

​

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/svz2J/10/

Comment: You could also use CSS3 transitions, if you wanted to avoid using a plugin. But browser support for this is still lacking.

Comment: Using CSS3 transitions is not the best solution at the moment. Besides applying jQuery Rotate plugin makes sense +1.

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks heaps for the help!

Comment: @ahren Just out of curiosity, would it be possible for one div to rotate in the same way when a button is clicked (rather than the div itself)?

Comment: Sure would. I've updated my answer above.

Comment: What an internet philanthropist. If I could give you more up-votes I would. Thanks heaps!

Answer (score 1):

I really suggest you use this plugin instead:
http://www.zachstronaut.com/posts/2009/08/07/jquery-animate-css-rotate-scale.html

I spend ages with the one ahren suggested on a project and ended up having to replace because of poor performance.

If its a relatively low process intensive thing then fair enough.. 
Just thought I'd weigh in.

Comment: That plugin doesn't cater for <IE9 - which (unfortunately!) still serves a large amount of the audience. Although, in saying that, I'm assuming this is going to be used for something public-facing.

Comment: aha, you reminded me... I hacked this to work in explorer 5 upwards but never got around to sending back to the original author. had to jam in bits of sylvester.js.. was such a pain..

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I had originally toyed around with this plugin but couldn't get it to do what I was after and gave up. Thankfully it's only one small rotate and only happens in one spot on the page so I think I'll get away with it performance-wise.