# How to get a picture to randomly move around a page and rotating angle when moving (using jQuery or CSS)

Tags: jquery, css, html, animation

I've got div randomly move around a page.

[old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10385950/how-to-get-a-div-to-randomly-move-around-a-page-using-jquery-or-css)

I replace the div with a picture like "arrow", now I want it randomly move, AND point the right direction, (change rotation angle when moving), not always point up.

[image: arrow]

I guess maybe rotate some angle when moving, but I don't konw how to calculate the angle between the old and new point.

Thanks in advance!!!

[image]

Comment: Check out this question for a rotation:
[enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3789984/jquery-how-do-i-animate-a-div-rotation

Regards

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    animateIMG();

});

function makeNewPosition(){

    // Get viewport dimensions (remove the dimension of the div)
    var h = $(window).height() - 50;
    var w = $(window).width() - 50;

    var nh = Math.floor(Math.random() * h);
    var nw = Math.floor(Math.random() * w);

    return [nh,nw];    

}

function animateIMG(){
    var newq = makeNewPosition();
    $('img').animate({ top: newq[0], left: newq[1] }, function(){
      animateIMG();        
    });

};
```

[**JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hEFYr/) with speed control http://jsfiddle.net/D6Svc/

Comment: Thanks, but I want it randomly move, and point the right direction, (change rotation angle when moving), not always point up. I don't konw how to calculate the angle between the old and new point.

Comment: Google "rectangular to polar transform".