# Trying to make a rotate animation

Tags: jquery, html, css

This is what ive tried so far. Im not getting an error in the console and the div isn't rotating either
http://jsfiddle.net/B8shT/

```
window.i = 10000;
function dothetwist()
{
    $('#box').animate( {
        step: function(now,fx) {
            $(this).css('-webkit-transform','rotatey('+now+'deg)');
        },
        duration: window.i,
        complete: function() {
            window.i=window.i-1000;
            dothetwist();
        }
    });       
}
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Shouldn't it be rotateY ?

Comment: jsfiddle automatically wraps a document.ready around

Comment: you still have to call it: `dothetwist();`

Comment: the function doesn't work whether i call it or not

Comment: The `.animate()` method expects two objects, the first indicating the property/properties to change, and the second giving the options like `step`, `complete`, etc. You've only supplied the second object. (And as for your "whether I call it or not", it is _guaranteed_ to do nothing if you don't call it...)

Comment: I suggest you check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3792033/2049063) for a better implementation of what you're trying to do

Comment: Try this.. Provide a `property` attribute and then, change `rotatey` to `rotate` .. Gives you http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/B8shT/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this is what you need.
[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/B8shT/2/)

```
window.i = 10000;

function dothetwist() {
  $( "#box" ).animate({
      rotate: 1000
  }, {
       step: function(now,fx) {
            $(this).css('-webkit-transform','rotate('+now+'deg)');
        },
    duration: window.i,
    complete: function() {
         window.i=window.i-1000;
            dothetwist();
    }
  });
}

$("#box").click(function() {
dothetwist();
});
```

P.S.: You can control the speed of rotation by changing "rotate: 1000" property to any other value.

Thanks @nnnnnn for getting me started.

Comment: Thanks for the effort