# Rotating an Element using jQuery addClass CSS

Tags: jquery, css, transform, addclass

So, I'm beginning to learn jQuery, and I'm trying to rotate an element using addClass and CSS transform. This is my code;

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/IAszu

It seems really basic, but I don't understand why it's not working.

I'd really appreciate your help.

Comment: How can you see the results if you're trying to rotate a solid color circle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `selector` is incorrect:

```
$(document).ready (function() {
  $("theDiv").addClass("rotate");
});
```

should be:

```
$(document).ready (function() {
  $("#theDiv").addClass("rotate");
});
```

and for maximum compatibility, you should add `-ms-transform: rotate(180deg)`
and `-webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);`.

With those changes it works for me.

#### EDIT: [Working CodePen with changes](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Dilan).

*Of course, I spent a solid minute wondering if you were trolling, since you were asking us to help you rotate... a circle.*

Comment: Oh it does work. Sorry. I was just expecting it to have an animation effect.

Comment: Oh, in that case -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3789984/jquery-how-do-i-animate-a-div-rotation