# how can i change node's rotation (transform: rotate(30deg)) with jquery and pure js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

1.which of the following is the best to use in-order to support as many browsers as possible?:

```
-webkit-transform: rotate(30deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(30deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(30deg);
-o-transform: rotate(30deg);
 transform: rotate(30deg);
```

and if i use jquery, does jquery offer a way to set just 1 that will handle the browser difference ?

2.what would be the difference using pure JS or jquery performance wise? and how do i even set it in pure JS?

considering i have like 100-300 items i have to change.that need to be changed really fast.

Comment: using jquery is more preferable than pure js.

Comment: Well, the vendor-specific prefixes are the very definition of non-portable, so.... not those ones. Typically you use *all* of them, if you want to support "as many browsers as possible", not any one of them.

Comment: @C-link Err, why? Can you back that up with any kind of reason?

Comment: if user's browser's js is blocked even then the jquery runs.

Comment: and would jquery wont offer a way to handle the browser difference, i mean like heigh() and width()

Comment: you can use js in jquery that's very well.

Comment: C-link you're saying that if someone has their JS disabled Jquery still runs ?

Comment: yes, it's why jquery is more preferable.

Comment: i am pretty sure that's completely wrong. as Jquery base its self on JS. ...

Comment: @C-link - Thats totally incorrect. jQuery is nothing but a JavaScript lib. It absolutely won't run if the user has JS disabled in his browser.

Comment: Its as obvious as it can get. Still: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2522784/will-jquery-work-in-a-javascript-disabled-browser

Comment: I guess your answer is here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/14016604/1852519

Comment: But I thought jquery runs with server from cdn etc. so it works.

Comment: @Maulik Suchakso basically using jquery and `transform` will take care of the browser difference right ? which make me thing that jquery is doing a little bit more then just setting the style - also checking browser etc.. how can i set the transformation in Pure JS ?

Comment: Yes, you are right. jQuery takes care of adding vendor specific code. I dont have idea about JavaScript. But I dont think so it would be doing. You can use jQuery here if you are confused between JS and jQuery. It always safe to use jQuery. It takes care of many things behalf of you!

Comment: I've found the way to set them using JS(i am a bit worried with performance is why i am considering native JS)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Use [-prefix-free](http://leaverou.github.io/prefixfree/)

2) Vanilla JavaScript is usually faster than eg. jQuery. However in many cases you need to write more code in order to achieve cross-browser compatibility.

The code would look something like (when using -prefix-free):

```
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll(".elementsToRotate"), function(elem) { 
    elem.style['transform'] = "rotate(30deg)";
});
```